# C++ - MFC - Set height of CMenu

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cmenu

Is there any option to set the height if a `CMenu`?

I know one can draw a custom menu item and use a custom size there `CMenu::MeasureItem`, but is there a way to set/change the height of the menu(bar) itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating the menu bar yourself? If so, is it derived from `CMFCMenuBar`? If both are yes, then I can offer a possible solution!

Comment: @AdrianMole Not at the moment but I will if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the height of a menu-bar is relatively easy, if your menu-bar is derived from the [CMFCMenuBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubar-class?view=vs-2019) class*. In this case, you simply need to override the `CalcLayout` member and specify the required height in the `.y` member of the returned `CSize` object. Here's a minimal example:

```cpp
// Class declaration...
class MyMenuBar : public CMFCMenuBar {
public:     // Standard constructors and destructor ...
    MyMenuBar(void) : CMFCMenuBar() {}
    inline  MyMenuBar(const MyMenuBar&) = delete;
    inline  MyMenuBar& operator = (MyMenuBar&) = delete;
    virtual ~MyMenuBar(void) {}
protected:  // Overrides for custom behaviour ...
    CSize CalcLayout(DWORD dwMode, int nLength = -1) override;
};

// Implementation...
CSize MyMenuBar::CalcLayout(DWORD dwMode, int nLength)
{
    CSize cs = CMFCMenuBar::CalcLayout(dwMode, nLength); // Call base-class to get width
    cs.cy = 42; // Set this to your desired menu-bar height (in pixels)
    return cs;
}
```

To use such a menu-bar, you need only to declare it as a member of your main frame window and then create it and set its style/properties when handling the `WM_CREATE` message for that frame window (typically, in `MFC` apps, this will be in the `OnCreate()` member override).

*Note: You could, in theory, use this method with any base-class that has the `CalcLayout` member (such as `CMFCToolbar`); however, the `CMFCMenuBar` class allows the framework to handle all other expected actions from the contained menu.*

Comment: The question concerne the CMenu and not CMenuBar

Comment: @Landstalker OP said, "*is there a way to set/change the height of the menu(**bar**) itself?*"

Comment: ... and note: MFC does not provide a "CMenuBar" class!